# Rhino.Mocks: can AssertWasCalled use a custom IEqualityComparer when comparing the method arguments?

Tags: rhino-mocks

I have the following code snippet:

```
Action<IProbingErrorHandler> handlerAction = x => x.Post(sourceContext, channelId, probingError);
var handler = MockRepository.GenerateStub<IProbingErrorHandler>();
handler.Stub(handlerAction);
...
handler.AssertWasCalled(handlerAction);
```

Unfortunately, I had to implement the Equals method in the argument types in order for the last assertion to work. Is there a way to use a custom IEqualityComparer implementation instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using [custom argument constraints](http://ayende.com/wiki/Rhino%20Mocks%203.5.ashx#Complexexpressions). This will let you write something like:

```
handler
    .Stub(x => x.Post(Arg<string>.Matches(s => ...), ..., ...)) 
    .Return(something);
```

Check the [Rhino Mocks constraints reference](http://ayende.com/wiki/Rhino%20Mocks%203.5.ashx#ConstraintsReference) for some of the built in matchers. If none of those do what you need, you can create your own by subclassing `AbstractConstraint` or one of the existing matchers.